# How to get a file path or a file name in netrw of Vim

Tags: vim, netrw

I would like to get a file path or a file name in netrw easily.

Is there any way to get a file path or a file name in netrw of Vim?

Comment: Remark, `s:NetrwGetWord()` function gets the filename under the cursor, but need a hack to call the s: functions https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17866/are-script-local-functions-sfuncname-unit-testable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the file name under cursor in netrw, copy it to the buffer with `y` and enter the following command: `:echo @%."/".@"`.

Explanation: `@{0-9a-z".=*+}` executes the contents of the register `{0-9a-z".=*+}`. The `%` register is a name of the current file. For netrw, this is the name of the open directory. The `"` register contains the copied file name. The `.` operator means concatenation of the strings in the vimscript.